# hunspell dictionary not recognized in Thunderbird 102, when installed as Debian package

Tags: debian, thunderbird, spell-checking, hunspell

On Debian 12, I have installed additional language hunspell dictionaries:

But when I start Thunderbird 102, it does not see them. When I click on Languages, it only offers the default `English (United States)`

Hunspell dictionary works when I install the dictionary locally as Addon. But then, I would have to install it individually for all my profiles.

Howe can I install hunspell dictionary as Debian package and use it in Thunderbird ?

Comment: What DE are you using ? How do you launch thunderbird ? Is it identical (only showing default language) if you launch Thunderbird from console ?

Comment: I launch thunderbird as: `thunderbird-bin -P <profile>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works:

in the thunderbird .desktop file, at the `Exec=` line, add env enviroment path to hunspel dictionaries:

```
Exec=env DICPATH=/usr/share/hunspell
```